# Change language to frensh for fullcalendar V0.0.0

Tags: view, fullcalendar, laravel-blade, laravel-7

Hello I am using Fullcalendar V.0.0 with laravel 7 but I can't change the fullcalendar to French because I can't find any documentation for fullcalendar V0.0.0, I only find for other versions. Any ideas to change it to French?

This is my code :

```
<script src=" {{ asset('js/fullcalendar.js')}}"></script>
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            height: "auto",
            selectable: true,
            droppable: true,
            defaultView: 'month',
            yearColumns: 3,
            editable: true,
            draggable: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'year,month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            dayClick: function(date, events, view) {
                $('#start').val(convert(date));
                $('#modalDialog').modal('show');
            },
            events: "{{ route('admin.rdv') }}",
            eventDrop: function(event) {
                console.log(event.id);
            }, 
});
```

Comment: `Fullcalendar V.0.0` isn't a real version. Where did you get that from? The versions start at 1 and are currently on 5.5.0. Your syntax makes it look like you're probably using a version between 1 and 3, but you can double-check by looking inside the fullcalendar.js file.

Comment: For v2.x and v3.x the language documentation can be found at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/localization (the API is the same as for V2, so there isn't separate documentation), and for v1 it's at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/localization. Not hard to find (you can just go to https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc and select the version from the dropdown). So once you've checked your real version you should be ok to proceed.

Comment: I Understand thank you but that's the version that I am having in my fullcalendar.js /*!
 * FullCalendar v0.0.0
 * Docs & License: https://fullcalendar.io/
 * (c) 2017 Adam Shaw
 */

Comment: I took it from here     https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/xhahIV

Comment: Someone has modified that file. Download a genuine copy from fullCalendar's website or a reputable CDN

Comment: e.g. if you use a genuine version of fullCalendar such as this one https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@3.9.0/dist/fullcalendar.min.js you'll see the real version at the top of the file (and of course in this case it happens to be in the URL but it's not always like that)

Comment: Okey Thank you so much ,I am gonna use the ones in the official fullcalendar websites .

Comment: Ok. Bear in mind that version 4 and above have very different syntax compared to 3 and below, so you would have to re-write some parts of the code shown above. There are setup guides available though, plus a guide to upgrading is available on the site too. https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/releases gives you access to older releases though, if you prefer to stick with version 3.